# Delete previous rows with duplicate info google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Column A has a Timestamp
Column B has a string of numbers and letters that may be duplicated
Column C has other data associated with the data in A and B

How can I delete a row that contains duplicates in column B and leave the LAST entry (the one with the newest Timestamp)

It doesn't have to be deleted per se, I can pull the data into a new column if needed.  I just want unique values with the latest timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
function findCopyDeleteDupes()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var nodupes=[];
  var dupeRows=[];
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    var idx=nodupes.indexOf(rngA[i][1]);
    if(idx==-1)
    {
      nodupes.push(rngA[i][1]);
    }
    else
    {
      for(var j=0;j<rngA[i].length;j++)
      {
        rngA[idx][j]=rngA[i][j];
      }
      dupeRows.push(i+1);
    }
  }
  rng.setValues(rngA);
  for(var i=dupeRows.length-1;i>-1;i--)
  {
     sht.deleteRow(dupeRows[i])
  }
}
```